# Render scene onto custom mesh with three.js

Tags: three.js, webgl, uv-mapping

After messing around with [this demo of Three.js rendering a scene to a texture](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_rtt.html), I successfully replicated the essence of it in my project: amidst my main scene, there's a now sphere and a secondary scene is drawn on it via a `THREE.WebGLRenderTarget` buffer.

I don't really need a sphere, though, and that's where I've hit a huge brick wall. When trying to map the buffer onto my simple custom mesh, I get an infinite stream of the following errors:

```
three.js:23444 WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: pixelStorei: invalid parameter for  alignment
three.js:23557 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined
```

My geometry, approximating an [annular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_%28mathematics%29) shape, is created using [this code](http://pastebin.com/3By6BKF8). I've successfully UV-mapped a `canvas` onto it by passing `{map: new THREE.Texture(canvas)}` into the material options, but if I use `{map: myWebGLRenderTarget}` I get the errors above.

A cursory look through the call stack makes it look like three.js is assuming the presence of the `texture.image` attribute on `myWebGLRenderTarget` and attempting to call `clampToMaxSize` on it.

Is this a bug in three.js or am I simply doing something wrong? Since I only need flat rendering (with `MeshBasicMaterial`), one of the first thing I did when adapting the render-to-texture demo above was remove all trace of the shaders, and it worked great with just the sphere. Do I need those shaders back in order to use UV mapping and a custom mesh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what its worth, I was needlessly setting `needsUpdate = true` on my texture. (The handling of `needsUpdate` apparently assumes the presence of a `<canvas>` that the texture is based on.)

Comment: Nice, this fixed it for me.  `.needsUpdate` is automatically set to true when instancing a new material.

Comment: I was scratching my head for a while doing the same silly mistake. Thanks!